# add_image_size() cropped only if width of the image matches or is higher

Tags: images

I want to add a custom image size that is cropped, like this:

```
add_image_size( 'large-cropped', 700, 300, true );
```

It works fine. The only problem is that if the image size is for example 500x400, then it will create an image that is 500x300.

I only want it to create an image **if** the width is at least `700` pixels width.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do a check for the image size before you add the add_image_size in that case. You can use wp_get_attachment_metadata() to find the size of the image. https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_metadata