# Setting JPEG compression for custom image sizes doesn't work in specific cases

Tags: images, compression

I have a [custom image size](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_image_size/) `hello-image`:

```
add_image_size( 'hello-image', 700, 300, true );
```

Whenever an image is uploaded, I compress the cropped `hello-image` sized image to `40%` JPEG compression. It works great in all cases except...

### The problem

If the **width** of the original image is *greater* than `700px` it works just fine. But if the width of it is *less* than `700px`, the compression goes to around `0%`.

### How to test it

Download the following two images:

[BIG: 784px × 441px](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kc3Zs.jpg)

[SMALL: 670px × 377px](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3hNt3.jpg)

Then I have created a plugin which has all the relevant code:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: WPSE: custom image size and JPEG compression
Description: custom image size and JPEG compression
Author: WPSE
Version: 1.0
*/

// Set JPEG compression quality
add_filter('jpeg_quality', create_function('$quality', 'return 100;'));

add_action('added_post_meta', 'ad_update_jpeg_quality', 10, 4);

function ad_update_jpeg_quality($meta_id, $attach_id, $meta_key, $attach_meta) {

    if ($meta_key == '_wp_attachment_metadata') {

        $post = get_post($attach_id);

        if ($post->post_mime_type == 'image/jpeg' && is_array($attach_meta['sizes'])) {

            $pathinfo = pathinfo($attach_meta['file']);
            $uploads = wp_upload_dir();
            $dir = $uploads['basedir'] . '/' . $pathinfo['dirname'];

            foreach ($attach_meta['sizes'] as $size => $value) {

                $image = $dir . '/' . $value['file'];
                $resource = imagecreatefromjpeg($image);

                if ($size == 'large') {

                    // set the jpeg quality for 'large' size
                    imagejpeg($resource, $image, 35);

                } elseif ($size == 'medium') {

                    // set the jpeg quality for the 'medium' size
                    imagejpeg($resource, $image, 35);

                } elseif ($size == 'hello-image') {

                    // set the jpeg quality for the 'hello-image' size
                    imagejpeg($resource, $image, 40);

                } else {

                    // set the jpeg quality for the rest of sizes
                    imagejpeg($resource, $image, 35); // 38
                }

                imagedestroy($resource);
            }
        }
    }
}


// add custom image sizes to media uploader
function my_insert_custom_image_sizes( $sizes ) {
    // get the custom image sizes
    global $_wp_additional_image_sizes;
    // if there are none, just return the built-in sizes
    if ( empty( $_wp_additional_image_sizes ) )
        return $sizes;

    // add all the custom sizes to the built-in sizes
    foreach ( $_wp_additional_image_sizes as $id => $data ) {
        // take the size ID (e.g., 'my-name'), replace hyphens with spaces,
        // and capitalise the first letter of each word
        if ( !isset($sizes[$id]) )
            $sizes[$id] = ucfirst( str_replace( '-', ' ', $id ) );
    }

    return $sizes;
}

// Which custom image size selected by default
function my_set_default_image_size () {
    return 'hello-image';
}

function custom_image_setup () {
    // custom image sizes
    add_image_size( 'medium', 300, 9999 ); //  medium
    add_image_size( 'hello-image', 700, 300, true ); // custom
    add_image_size( 'large', 700, 3000 ); //  large

    add_filter( 'image_size_names_choose', 'my_insert_custom_image_sizes' );
    add_filter( 'pre_option_image_default_size', 'my_set_default_image_size' );
}

add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'custom_image_setup' );
```

Now, upload the *big* image and see how the `hello-image` image is compressed fine. Then upload the *small* image and see how the same image size is compressed terribly. So to clarify, this is the results:

```
700x300 = 40% compression
670x300 = 0% compression
```

Both of which are generated via the exact same custom image size. What is the cause of this and how can it be fixed?

I should highlight that my colleague posted a [question here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/271192/add-image-size-cropped-only-if-width-of-the-image-matches-or-is-higher) asking how to avoid creating this image size if the width is lower than `700px`... but I'm a WordPress geek who would rather resolve the cause of the problem than add a hacky fix to it.

Finally, I started seeing this problem in a recent WordPress update, so it may be a bug in core, as opposed to an issue in my code.

**Edit**: Read the [update](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/271195/setting-jpeg-compression-for-custom-image-sizes-doesnt-work-in-specific-cases#comment402886_271261).

Comment: Given the complexity of this question, I will bounty it 50 points when it's eligible.

Answer (score 6):

*Some suggestions:*

If you want to try out the *Image Editor API* you can try to replace

```
imagejpeg( $resource, $image, 35 );
```

with:

```
$editor = wp_get_image_editor( $image );  
if ( ! is_wp_error( $editor ) )
{
    $editor->set_quality( 35 );
    $editor->save( $image  );
}
unset( $editor );
```

Also try to test e.g. these parts:

```
$resource = imagecreatefromjpeg( $image );
if( false !== $resource )
{
    imagejpeg( $resource, $image, 35 );
    imagedestroy( $resource );
}
```

in a standalone PHP script, to make sure it's not a PHP or GD related issue.

PS: [Here's a different approach](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/163844/create-image-formats-with-different-qualities-when-uploading/165241#165241) where we try to modify the image quality **before** the image size is generated.

**Testing the plugin**

Let's check the plugin from the main question.

Test install

- WordPress version 4.9-alpha-40917
- PHP 7.0.19

[image: gd]
[image: imagick]

Here's the generated `hello-image` (670x300) size, of the SMALL (670 × 377) image, from the question, where we set the quality to 40:

```
imagejpeg( $resource, $image, 40 );
```

[image: q=40]

Here's the same but with the quality set to 0:

```
imagejpeg( $resource, $image, 0 );
```

[image: q=0]

So it looks like we **don't** get the same behavior as described in the question, that when the quality is set to 40, it becomes 0, for the `hello-image` size of the 670x377 original image.

Comment: Tried your approach with same [results](http://i.imgur.com/PVFUolt.jpg). Quite possibly the most bizarre issue. It can't be a PHP/GD issue because it compresses the image properly *if* the width is above `700px` as noted in the question. Did you have a chance to test this on your local environment? Before I look into alternative solution (as the one you linked), I'm hoping to get to the bottom of why this doesn't work. Mainly to *understand* how to troubleshoot this type of issue in the future given that WordPress is my actual career now. =) Wouldn't be surprised if we discovered a WP bug.

Comment: I tested the plugin and updated the answer. It looks like I can't replicate the problem on my test install.

Comment: Thank you very much for the update. I am looking into the cause of this now that it *may* appear to be a local issue. I will post an update soon (may take some days). A 1+ meanwhile!

Comment: A question. Is the `imagick` module really required to have this working?

Comment: No, I just included both info tables as I tested both `WP_Image_Editor_Imagick` and `WP_Image_Editor_GD` via the `wp_image_editors` filter.

Comment: ... and when I tested `WP_Image_Editor_Imagick`  I used the *Image Editor API* instead of `imagejpeg`

Comment: Ok, in my many years of coding and debugging, this makes no sense. I updated PHP from v5 to latest (v7.16), updated apache, deactivated all plugins, emptied function.php file and all that jazz. **Still** the same issue. Tested on a fresh install on the same server, it works fine. So something is making it not work. And how did I finally fix it? Are you ready for it... adjusting the image height from `300` to anything, like `301`. **THAT** compresses the custom image size correctly. In what way does this make any sense haha! Well, as the god ol' coder must say upon defeat: **** it, I'm done!

Comment: And thank you very much indeed for updating your alternative solution with the imagick approach. I tested it and it seems to work just fine! I have one lasting question, is there any benefit in using the imagick approach rather than the one I have here in terms of performance/image quality? I will definitely rewards this bounty to you because although you did not solve the core of the problem, you encouraged me to update things that I've left on the shelf, and offered a totally valid alternative solution. Not to mention that you took the time to test the code on your own environment. Thanks!

Comment: Oh and in case it wasn't clear, the alternative approach which you coded had the exact same issue with the compression on this particular image size being nearly 0%. That was the part when I spat on my screen. haha

Comment: @ChristineCooper I enjoyed reading your witty comments ;-) Maybe this is a mix of [Heisenbug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenbug#Mandelbug) and [Mandelbug](http://encyclopedia2.thefreedictionary.com/mandelbug) as I could not reproduce it ;-) I would recommend using the WP Editor API if possible, that way it should work both for GD and Imagick. The latter seems to be more advanced in general but many things from that library are not available through the WP Editor API. I've not looked into performance but have heard that GD might be available on more servers.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting, I tried it and the small image gets displayed 670x300 and the big image 700x300. Seems to me like its is doing exactly what it needs to do, it crops the image if either the height or width are above the image type (or both).

I understand you only want to crop the image if the height is higher? Then using this would work:

```
  add_image_size( 'hello-world', 700, 0, true );
```

I re-upload the images after that and the small images gets displayed 670 by 377 and the big image 700 by 394. I uploaded another smaller version (516x290) and it does not get cropped at all.

Although when you upload an image like 690x4000 it also does not get cropped.

Comment: This does not actually resolve the problem. Please note that I am looking for the reason *why* the `670x300` is compressed to `0%` and the `700x300` compressed to `40%`. Both of which are generated via the exact same image size, so the compression should be set to `40%` on **both**. I have updated my question a bit to clarify the question further. Please let me know if you need any further clarification.